# Сделал класс динамический список. Нужно удалять те слова из предложений списка, в которых есть введенная мною буква

Tags: c++, строки, классы, список

Иногда работает, а иногда нет, проблема где-то в функции `DeleteWords`, когда не роботает то выдает ошибку

```
Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения.
ptr было 0x2A2A2A2A.
```

Указывает на строку `while (*ptr != '\0' && *ptr != NULL && *ptr!='\n')`
Код с украинскими комментариями:

```
// Двохзв'язний список
#include "pch.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#define K 300

struct Node                                // Структура, яка є основою списку
{
    char array[K];                         // Значення array буде передаватися у список
    Node *Next, *Prev;                     // Вказівники на адреси попереднього і наступного елементів списку
};

class List                                 // Створємо клас список
{
public:
    Node *Head, *Tail;                     // Вказівники на адреси початку та кінця списку
    List() :Head(NULL), Tail(NULL) {};     // Ініціалізуємо адреси як пусті
    ~List();                               // Прототип деструктора
    void ShowLast();                       // Прототип функції відображення списку на екрані з останнього елементу
    void ShowFirst();                      // Прототип функції відображення списку на екрані з першого елементу
    void Add(char x[K]);                   // Прототип функції додавання елементів у список
    void DeleteWords(char letter);                     // Прототип функції з індивідуального завдання
};

List::~List()                             // Деструктор
{
    while (Head)                          // Поки за адресою на початок списка щось є
    {
        Tail = Head->Next;                // Резервна копія адреси наступної ланки списку
        delete Head;                      // Очищення пам'яті від перошої ланки
        Head = Tail;                      // Зміна адреси початку на адресу наступного елемента
    }
}

void List::Add(char x[K])
{
    Node *temp = new Node;               // Виділяємо пам'ять під новий елемент структури
    temp->Next = NULL;                   // Вказуємо що початкове значення за даною адресою - пусте
    strcpy(temp->array, x);              // Записуємо значення у структуру

    if (Head != NULL)                    // Якщо список не пустий
    {
        temp->Prev = Tail;               // Вказуємо адресу попереднього елементу за хвостом у відповідне поле
        Tail->Next = temp;               // Вказуємо адресу наступного елементу за хвостом
        Tail = temp;                     // Міняємо адресу хвоста
    }
    else                                 // Якщо список пустий
    {
        temp->Prev = NULL;               // Попередній елемент вказує у пустоту
        Head = Tail = temp;              // Голова=Хвіст=*той елемент, який ми тільки що додали*
    }
}

void List::ShowLast()
{
    // ВИВОДИМО СПИСОК З КІНЦЯ
    Node *temp = Tail;                   // Тимчасовий вказівник на адресу останнього елементу

    while (temp != NULL)                 // Тимчасово вказуємо на адресу першого елементу
    {
        cout << temp->array << " ";      // Виводимо значення на екран
        temp = temp->Prev;               // Вказуємо, що потрібна адреса попереднього елементу
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void List::ShowFirst()
{
    Node *temp = Tail;                   // Тимчасовий вказівник на адресу останнього елементу

    // ВИВОДИМО СПИСОК З ПОЧАТКУ
    temp = Head;                         // Тимчасово вказуємо на адресу першого елементу
    while (temp != NULL)                 // Допоки не зустрінемо пусте значення
    {
        cout << temp->array << " ";      // Виводим всі значення на екран
        temp = temp->Next;               // Зміна адреси на адресу наступного елементу
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void List::DeleteWords(char letter)
{
    Node *temp = Tail;                   // Тимчасовий вказівник на адресу останнього елементу

    // ВИВОДИМО СПИСОК З ПОЧАТКУ
    temp = Head;                         // Тимчасово вказуємо на адресу першого елементу
    while (temp != NULL)                 // Допоки не зустрінемо пусте значення
    {
        char *ptr = temp->array;         // Вказівник на початок речення    
        char *dod = temp->array;         // Додатковий вказівник на початок речення
        while (*ptr != '\0' && *ptr != NULL && *ptr!='\n')  // Допоки не кінець речення
        {
            if (*ptr == ' ')             // Якщо вказівник потрапив на пробіл
            { 
                dod = ptr;               // Додатковий вказівник переносимо на це місце
                ptr++;                   // Шукаємо далі кінець слова
            }
            if (*ptr == letter)          // Якщо вказівник потрапив на нашу буку 
            {
                while (*ptr != ' ')      // Допоки не кінець слова
                {
                    ptr++;               // Шукаємо кінець слова
                }
                while (dod != ptr)       // Допоки додатковий вказівник не дійшов до кінця слова
                {
                    *dod = '*';          // Замінюємо слово на "*"
                    dod++;               // Йдемо до кінця слова
                }

                ptr++; continue;         // Рухаємо основний вказівник
            }
            ptr++;                       // Рухаємо основний вказівник
        }
        temp = temp->Next;               // Зміна адреси на адресу наступного елементу
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    system("CLS");
    List list;                           // Об'явимо змінну, ти якої - список
    char array[K];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)          // Введемо елементи списку
    {
        cout << "Enter " << i+1 << " element of the list:" << endl;
        gets_s(array);
        list.Add(array);
    }

    list.ShowFirst();                    // Відображаємо список з початку на екрані

    char letter;
    cout << "Enter the letter: ";
    cin >> letter;

    list.DeleteWords(letter);
    list.ShowFirst();

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Решил добавлением '\0': while (*ptr != ' ' && *ptr != ',' && *ptr != '\0')

Answer (score 0):

Судя по коду, вы не удаляете слова из символьного массива, а заменяете их звездочками.

Следующий цикл внутри if-предложения имеет неопределенное поведение

```
            while (*ptr != ' ')      // Допоки не кінець слова
            {
                ptr++;               // Шукаємо кінець слова
            }
```

так как нет проверки на конец строки, то есть на символ `'\0'`. Поэтому указатель `ptr` может переместиться за пределы символьного массива.